# What is a wallop of money?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does *wallop of money* mean in the following:

> That is one hell of a wallop of money

It is from a BBC film about Warren Buffet.

Comment: What part are ou having trouble with?

Comment: I don't understand the whole sentence.

Comment: A lot of money!!

Comment: So you don't know what any of the words mean?

Comment: If you don't understand the whole sentence, then you'll likely want to have a look at the site for [ell.SE].

Comment: I don't understand part "wallop of money". I have got answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "That is a lot of money". [Emphatically]

To [Wallop](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wallop) means something along the lines of "To strike with a hard blow". A *wallop* is a hard punch.

[To pack a wallop](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pack+a+wallop) is an idiom. I have often heard that spicy foods can "pack a wallop".

I also thought *wallop* could mean a large amount or sum, but I can't find the reference.